# VideoView:Avoiding fullscreen black flash

Tags: android, android-videoview

I'm trying to play a video, where the first and last frame of the video match a static background image. However I see a fullscreen black flash just before and after the movie clip. 
How can I avoid this fullscreen black flash?

Comment: Can you include the code that you are using? Perhaps it would be a good idea just to load the final image in the background first and then just kill your video player and have the static image sitting there waiting for you?

Comment: Similar question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343350/videoview-black-flash-before-and-after-playing

Answer (score 0):

See here on how to avoid the fullscreen black flash:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/ZSe73VtmTE8