# video view to avoid or clear background of phone screen in android

Tags: android

How to avoid or clear background of phone screen using video view in android?

[1]: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pl9W.png )

```
View.OnClickListener handleOnClickVideo(final ImageView button1) {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {

                Constant.database = new MyHelper(getApplicationContext());
                Constant.sqldb = Constant.database.getReadableDatabase();
                imageShowed.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                videoShowed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mVideoView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                bar.show();
                int newVideoId = button1.getId();
                Constant.database.getContentValues(newVideoId);
                String getVideo = "https://whootin.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/upload/21e0b4df-120d-4c9f-ad4a-b475bb844b48/Homemade%20Steak%20Fajitas%20Recipe%20-%20Laura%20Vitale%20-%20Laura%20in%20the%20.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJF5QHW2P5ZLAGVDQ&Signature=EGU5xUP3E8QpkTrG71dr0MvR2hQ%3D&Expires=1381916425";//GetSet.getVideo();
                Log.d("video", getVideo);
                mVideoView.setSoundEffectsEnabled(true);
                mVideoView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                mediaController.setAnchorView(mVideoView);
                mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(getVideo));
                mVideoView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
                mVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
                mVideoView.requestFocus();
                mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(PreparedListener);
                Constant.database.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
                bar.dismiss();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

i have attached my code.

Comment: Question is not clear.

Comment: Did you see the link. the video is playing in videoview. but before playing videoview show screen like in that link. how it should be avoid or clear or set black screen.

Comment: please reply me. and thank you for your response for this post.

Comment: You mean, you wants to make the background transparent. Right?

Comment: i already set that i have attached my code

Comment: MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener PreparedListener = new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

  @Override
  public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer m) {
   try {
    mp = m;
    if (mp.isPlaying()) {

     //mVideoView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
     mp.stop();
     mp.release();
     mp = new MediaPlayer();

    }
    mVideoView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    mp.start();
    bar.dismiss();

   } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
 };

Comment: So you wants to avoid that black screen flashing before video starts playing. Right?

Comment: loaded screen like this.  [1]: (http://i.stack.imgur.com/QMeWI.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the visibility of `mVideoView` as `GONE` before video starts.

```
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

    View placeholder = (View) findViewById(R.id.placeholder);

    placeholder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Or you can change the `ZOrder` of `mVideoView` like this

```
videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
```

For reference see this question: [Android VideoView black screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765629/android-videoview-black-screen)

Comment: i have just seen this answer. Thank you for your response. i already upvoted. i check now afterthat i will be told you.