# How to display video instead of black screen in Android VideoView before start

Tags: java, android, video

I'm playing a video in VideoView on Android Studio. The video starts when I click on the video. How can I get it to display the video instead of a black screen before I click the video to start? I also want to make the video full screen when it is clicked and I'm also struggling to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

LegWorkouts.java

```
burpeeButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            VideoView mVideoView2 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.burpees);

            String uriPath = "android.resource://com.delta.object.newandroidproject/"+R.raw.burpees;
            Uri uri1 = Uri.parse(uriPath);
            mVideoView2.setVideoURI(uri1);
            mVideoView2.requestFocus();
            mVideoView2.start();

        }
    });
```

LegWorkouts.xml

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/burpees"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="131dp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/secondJump"
    android:layout_below="@+id/secondJump"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

Comment: black screen is duplicate problem. [android-videoview-black-screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765629/android-videoview-black-screen)

Answer (score -1):

Use seekTo to with time in milliseconds, to display image at the second in the video.

Using zero would set it to the first frame of the video.
    //Initialize the videoView before onClickListener

```
    VideoView mVideoView2 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.burpees);
    String uriPath = "android.resource://com.delta.object.newandroidproject/"+R.raw.burpees;
    Uri uri1 = Uri.parse(uriPath);
    mVideoView2.setVideoURI(uri1);
    **mVideoView2.seekTo(0);**

burpeeButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    mVideoView2.requestFocus();
    mVideoView2.start();
}
```

Comment: Your onClick() is setting up the video. You will need to move the code to initialize the video, so that it is displayed BEFORE you wait for the click.