# While playing a video in videoview from raw folder , a black screen comes before startng the video

Tags: android, webview

While playing a video in videoview  from raw folder , a black screen comes before starting the video.

My question is how to remove that black screen which seems like a jerk ?

I am using below code to start video

```
int raw = getResources().getIdentifier("login", "raw", getPackageName());
    String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + raw;
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
    videoView.start();
```

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9982246/7746134

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code to get rid of it

```
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(mp.getCurrentPosition() != 0){
                    View placeholder = findViewById(R.id.placeholder);
                    placeholder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    new Handler().postDelayed(this, 50);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```