# Black Flickering When Playing Video on Android 5

Tags: java, android, video, xamarin

I have a simple Android toilet app that flushes when the user presses a button. The problem is: On Android 5, one of the videos flickers at the beginning and end (black flashing).

I haven't seen this issue on Android 4 or 6 so far.

Here's a video clip of the issue: https://youtu.be/8OgrWQODIrc

Any suggestions to fix?

Note: The toilet is a PNG with a transparent hole over top of the "flush" video.

Comment: I must say, I am impressed by your attention to detail for someone making a simple toilet app.

Comment: @MikeNakis I guess it's my OCD/perfectionist side wanting to fix this issue.

Comment: Are you sure it is related to the android version and not to the device?  To me it seems like something may be slowing down the device.  The first (long) blackness may be due to the device trying to simultaneously load and play the sound of the flushing toilet.  And then who knows, maybe something is completely messed up and the device also freezes when it is doing other housekeeping after the sound has completed.

Comment: @MikeNakis I'm not sure. I have tested on two different devices (Galaxy S6 and an off-brand tablet), both running Android 5 and the issue happens on both. The issue doesn't happen on an older Nexus 5 running Android 4.4. The "sound" is built into the MP4 video file, it's not a separate clip.

Comment: Okay, so the blackness occurs in the video, when the video starts, and when the video ends, right?

Comment: @MikeNakis Correct.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343350/videoview-black-flash-before-and-after-playing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765629/android-videoview-black-screen/16302973

Comment: @MikeNakis I already tried the accepted solution in the second link (I left a comment there back in August). The accepted solution in the first link seems hack-ish, but I'll have to try it. What doesn't make sense is I have another video in this app that plays fine (no black flickering) and is longer in length than the problem video.