# videoview screen fade black in android TV

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-video-player, android-tv

I try to  play video from raw folder.I wrote some codes and everything is perfect in device.

```
    String UrlPath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.background_video;
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(UrlPath));
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();
```

but  i have problem android TV.first  time i created both projects(device and TV).
when i run my project in android tv,screen getting fade black,It looks like  it adds some transparent black view in my VideoView.
how i can solve this problem?
thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the solution in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717906/videoview-inside-fragment-causes-black-screen-flicking) by adding a SurfaceView. It looks like this:

```
<SurfaceView
android:layout_width="0px"
android:layout_height="0px" />
```

Another SO question that can help you with this problem is this: [VideoView black flash before and after playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343350/videoview-black-flash-before-and-after-playing)